# Using string interpolation in innerHTML in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am designing a game, and I am dynamically creating statements with blanks inside and ask the players to fill in the blanks. I need string interpolation to record user's input, but I also need to set dynamic innerHTML because the blanks can be anywhere in the statement.

I know this sounds vague, here is relevant code examples:

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="range" step="1" min="0" max="100" class="slider 
       (input)="sliderMoved($event)">

<div class="question" [innerHTML]="questionStatement"></div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
display=50;

questionStatement='<div class="percent">{{display}}%</div> 
                   of Americans have a university degree.'

questionStatementExample2='Canada is <div class="percent">{{display}}%</div> 
                           the size of America.'

sliderMoved(event: any) {this.display=event.target.value;}
```

The `questionStatement` can have `<div class="percent">{{display}}%</div>` in anywhere in the sentence, hence the need of dynamic entry point.

Here, string interpolation (`{{display}}`) does not work in `innerHTML`. It will show up on screen literally as `{{display}}`. What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) should help you out here. If you modify your component like below your problem should be solved.

**app.component.ts**

```
display = 50;

questionStatement = `<div class="percent">${this.display}%</div> of Americans have a university degree.`

sliderMoved(event: any) {
    this.display=event.target.value;
    this.questionStatement = `<div class="percent">${this.display}%</div> of Americans have a university degree.`
}
```

Comment: Also just to add a small note: To make sure that the class also gets applied, I need to add: encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.none to app.component.ts

Comment: Hi, I tried this method and it works only if I type the literal string word by word inside the sliderMoved method, e.g.:  `this.questionStatement='<div class="percent">${this.display}%</div> of Americans have a university degree.'` . It does not work when I use a variable to replace the literal string, for instance,  `var replacement='<div class="percent">${this.display}%</div> of Americans have a university degree.'; this.questionStatement=this.replacement;`does not work (it still shows the same number as it was first defined). Any idea how to work around it?

Comment: Cool, let me know if you face issue.

Comment: @PalSingh sir i have returned innerHTML with Template expression but i got returned same ${this.tenantName} string instead of value.can you please help me on that how to get value ?

Comment: @KapilSoni Maybe your issue us solved. If not, please share a code sample of your issue.